# How to write a TeX macro that accepts a number or a \count register as argument?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

What's the most simple way, *in plain TeX*, to define a `\macro` that can be used as:

```
\macro{10}

\macro{\mycount}
```

such that I can then assign the number to a `\count` and manipulate it?

Note:

```
\def\macro#1{...\number#1 ...}
```

is *not* what I want.

In other words, how can I modify the following TeX code (see ex 10.4 of *The TeXbook*):

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}

\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\def\doticks#1{\count255=#1%
\ifnum\count255=1%
    \tmp%
\else%
    \advance \count255 by -1\relax%
    \tmp\doticks\count255%
\fi}

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks\number#1}}}
```

In such a way that:

```
\ruler{10}

\count255=10
\ruler{\count255}
\bye
```

outputs a page with two 10 centimetres rulers drawn on it?

(current code gives a `Missing number` error).

Comment: I was using `\count255` because the TeXbook mentions that it *is* a scratch register. However I just tried Ian solution and replacing `\mycount` with `\count255` it doesn't work, so some macro in there is using `\count255` too...

Comment: @Bakuriu: Note his solution braces the argument for `\doticks`... which is necessary.

Comment: @Bakuriu, after adding the braces (`\doticks{\number#1}`), there is also the `%` in `\def\doticks#1{\count255=#1%` which is problematic, because the `\ifnum` test may be expanded before the assignment is done. If you do `\expandafter\doticks\expandafter{\number#1}` on one hand and on the other hand `\def\doticks#1{\count255=#1 ` _without a `%`_ (but with a space), the it will be ok. See my upcoming answer for the complete thing (there are other modifications too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Werner's suggestion of using your own counter, I think you need braces around `\number#1`, otherwise `\doticks` picks up `\number` as its argument.

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}

\newcount\mycount
\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\def\doticks#1{\mycount=#1%
\ifnum\mycount=1%
    \tmp%
\else%
    \advance \mycount by -1\relax%
    \tmp\doticks\mycount%
\fi}

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{\number#1}}}} % <--- new braces here

\ruler{10}

\mycount=10
\ruler{\mycount}
\bye
```

Comment: Damn, I lost *hours* for this and turns out I forgot one pair of braces. I must mention that the use of `\newcount` seems *required*. If I copy-paste your solution and replace `\mycount` with `\count255` inside the `\doticks` macro I still get a `Missing number ...` error. Next time I'll make sure to avoid even so-called scratch registers...

Comment: If you wish to use `\count255`, you need to enclose it in braces whenever it is passed to `\doticks` (there are two locations).

Comment: @Werner Right. I'm probably too affected by programming languages where identifiers are single tokens and can contain digits, while `\count255` contains two tokens... From now on until I learn I should really *first* enclose *any* argument with braces, and *afterwards* ask my self if they contain a single token or not and eventually remove them. Maybe doing this I'll finally learn.

Comment: You're doing ten nested `\ifnum`; not really an issue with ten, it might be for longer recursions.

Comment: All `%` in the definition of `\doticks` are either wrong or redundant. Precisely, the first should be `\relax`, the second should be removed and the others are redundant.

Comment: @Bakuriu `\count255` is 4 tokens not two

Answer (score 6):

Use `\afterassignment` and a group, so not to clobber the value of `\count255`. Also use tail recursion.

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt }

\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\def\doticks#1{\begingroup\afterassignment\dodoticks\count255=#1\endgroup}
\def\dodoticks{%
  \tmp
  \ifnum\count255=1
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \advance \count255 by -1
    \let\next\dodoticks
  \fi
  \next
}

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{#1}}}}

\ruler{10}

\count255=10
\ruler{\count255}

\bigskip

{\tt\string\count255} is \number\count255

\bye
```

[image]

The same with some `@`'s:

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt }

\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\catcode`@=11
\def\doticks#1{\begingroup\afterassignment\d@ticks\count@=#1\endgroup}
\def\d@ticks{%
  \tmp
  \ifnum\count@=\@ne
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \advance \count255 by \m@ne
    \let\next\d@ticks
  \fi
  \next
}
\catcode`@=12
\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{#1}}}}

\ruler{10}

\count255=10
\ruler{\count255}

\bigskip

{\tt\string\count255} is \number\count255

\bye
```

Comment: you can optimize your `\d@ticks` via `\ifnum\count@=\@ne\else\advance\count@\m@ne\expandafter\d@ticks\fi` (or `\ifnum\count@>\@ne etc...` which perhaps is faster than testing for equality and then `\else`. I don't know)

Comment: @jfbu I used Knuth style tail recursion on purpose.

Comment: I see, I thought `\expandafter\stuff\fi` was also called tail recursion. Should I delete my comment?

Comment: @jfbu It *is* tail recursion: the important thing is that the conditional is removed from the input stream and both methods do it. Actually, removing `\let\next\relax` and changing `\let\next\d@ticks` into `\expandafter\d@ticks` should be more efficient. As I said, I just wanted to do it Knuth-style.

Answer (score 6):

A version without using a temp count register. Requires etex but pdftex includes that by default.

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}



\def\doticks #1{%
 \hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}%
\ifnum#1>0
  \expandafter\doticks\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
\fi
}

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{#1}}}}

\ruler{10}

\newcount\mycnt

\mycnt=10

\ruler{\mycnt}

\nopagenumbers
\bye
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\numexpr` is *not* expandable, so unless you add `\number` in front of it the first two `\expandafter` tokens do nothing.

Comment: @egreg, they did something when they were written (as I had `\the`) seems like I took that out before posting, but left the expandafter:( will fix

Comment: @egreg `\the` is quicker than `\number` when prefixing a `\numexpr`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you don't need the `\relax`, the closing brace will stop the `\numexpr`, (after the `\expandafter` has taken care of the `fi`).

Comment: @jfbu yes I know but it's easier to put it there than worry about not needing it (it would be needed if the outer exandafters were removed as then the `{}` would be macro delimiters and be gone by the time numexpr was evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it in the following (not very efficient!) style:

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}

\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\def\doticks#1{\count255=#1\relax
\ifnum\count255=1
    \tmp
\else
    \advance \count255 by -1
    \tmp\doticks{\count255 }%
\fi}

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{#1}}}}

\ruler{10}

\count255=5

\ruler{\count255}

\nopagenumbers
\bye
```

> [image: rulers]

Actually, this code (maybe I should have read it) indeed does nest many `\if..\fi` so to avoid that, one could do the (somewhat silly but working):

```
\def\doticks#1{\count255=#1\relax
\tmp
\ifnum\count255=1 
      \let\next\relax
\else
    \def\next {\doticks{\count255 }}%
    \advance \count255 by -1
\fi
\next }
```

Anyway, there is in the Plain format a loop which it is very natural to use here:

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}

\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\def\doticks #1{\count255=#1\relax
\loop 
  \tmp
\ifnum\count255>1 
  \advance\count255 by -1
\repeat
}

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{#1}}}}

\ruler{10}

\newcount\mycnt

\mycnt=10

\ruler{\mycnt}

\nopagenumbers
\bye
```

> [image: rulers]

If one wants to preserve as `egreg` the value stored in `\count 255` one can also do it without creating a group. It is irrelevant for the task at hand, but for other situations it could be useful to not create a group.

(for efficiency one should also do as `egreg` and use `\count@`, `@ne`, `m@ne` etc...)

```
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}

\def\tmp{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}

\def\doticks #1{\edef\restorecountxxlv{\count255=\the\count255\relax}%
                \count255=#1\relax \dotickticks \restorecountxxlv }

\def\dotickticks{\tmp
                 \ifnum\count255>1 
                   \advance\count255 by -1 
                   \expandafter\dotickticks
                 \fi }

\def\ruler#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\doticks{#1}}}}

\count255 7

\ruler{10}

{\tt\string\count 255} stores \the\count255

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=3

\ruler{\cnt}

{\tt\string\count 255} stores \the\count255

\bye
```

> [image: rulers rule]