# How to assign a macro's expansion to a \count?

Tags: tex-core, counters, expansion

`\findtoken` is a macro that finds the index (starting at zero) of (the full expansion of) its parameter `#1` in a predefined list ("a", "b", "c", "d");
it stops compilation if this expansion isn't in the list.

It seems to work fine for typesetting this index,
but I'd like to be able to also assign this number to a `\count`,
such that `\newcount\mycount \mycount=\findtoken{c}\relax \the\mycount`
would typeset "2".

I've tried many combinations of `\expandafter` in the assignment, and
I've read [Why does the TeX scanner process tokens for register numbers and macro names differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349420)
and [How to write a TeX macro that accepts a number or a \count register as argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144870) ,
but couldn't come up with a way of doing that.

So, is it possible?

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter

\newcount\mycount
\newcommand*{\findtoken}[1]{%
  % input (#1): a b c d <anything else>
  %     output: 0 1 2 3 error
  \begingroup     % protect scratch macros
  \edef\@tempa{\expanded{#1}}%
  \@tempswafalse  % did anything match?
  \@tempcnta=\z@  % index of the list
  % loop
  \@for\@tempb:={a,b,c,d}\do{%
    % if they match, record the current index
    \ifx\@tempb\@tempa
      \@tempswatrue
      \expandafter\aftergroup\the\@tempcnta
    \fi
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  }% end of loop
  \if@tempswa\else
    \STOPCOMPILATION
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\lettera{a}
Checking whether \string\findtoken\ works:
\findtoken{\lettera},
\findtoken{a},
\findtoken{b},
\findtoken{c},
\findtoken{d}.
% uncomment the next line to stop compilation:
% \findtoken{x}

% now, trying to assign \findtoken's expansion into \mycount:
% \mycount\findtoken{c}\relax
% ^ what to write above?! ^

\string\mycount's value is: \the\mycount.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\findtoken` is not expandable, it involves `\begingroup`, `\edef`, ..... so no amount of `\expandafter` will produce a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers mention the core: your macro, if used in the syntax `\register=\macro`, must *expand* to the macro value, because the assignment is performed after expansion. No un-expandable control sequences (like `\begingroup` or `\edef`) may be set here.

I add a very short example of an expandable alternative to your macro. TeX has a very compact language.

```
\newcount\mycount

\def\findtoken #1{%
   \ifcase\numexpr \expandafter`#1-`a\relax 
      0\or 1\or 2\or 3\else \STOPCOMPILATION \fi
}

\def\lettera{a}
Checking whether \string\findtoken\ works:
\findtoken{\lettera},
\findtoken{a},
\findtoken{b},
\findtoken{c},
\findtoken{d}.
% uncomment the next line to stop compilation:
% \findtoken{x}

% now, trying to assign \findtoken's expansion into \mycount:
\mycount=\findtoken{c}\relax

\string\mycount's value is: \the\mycount.
```

**Edit:** Due to the comment I show another compact and expandable solution:

```
\newcount\mycount
\def\declcode#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname findtoken:#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\findtoken#1{\ifcsname findtoken:#1\endcsname
   \csname findtoken:#1\endcsname \else \STOPCOMPILATION \fi
}

\declcode{a}{0}
\declcode{b}{1}
\declcode{c}{2}
\declcode{d}{3}

\def\lettera{a}
Checking whether \string\findtoken\ works:
\findtoken{\lettera},
\findtoken{a},
\findtoken{b},
\findtoken{c},
\findtoken{d}.
% uncomment the next line to stop compilation:
% \findtoken{x}

% now, trying to assign \findtoken's expansion into \mycount:
\mycount=\findtoken{c}\relax

\string\mycount's value is: \the\mycount.
```

Comment: hm, it seems this depends upon the list chars having consecutive charcodes, which is the case in my MWE but not in my actual-case... but that's my fault when reducing the problem to a MWE, I shouldn't have used consecutive letters.

Comment: @DanielDiniz OK, I added another solution.

Comment: @wipet Now you cannot say that your second version is more compact than mine. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg it depends on how do you describe "compact": wipet does not need to load latex3 o_O

Comment: @DanielDiniz what does the "actual case" look like?

Comment: non-consecutive, single ASCII letters (could be "gakm" -> "0123", etc)

Comment: So, say, "google" should count "6" (letters could be repeated, not assigned one to one in a map).

Comment: that's not how the macro works. it will never receive "google" as input; it only takes single letters (other macros take care of that). it's not a macro to count letters in a word, it just converts a single letter into a number 0 <= n <= 9. when I wrote "gakm" -> "0123" I meant that it could be the mapping is "g"->0, "a"->1, "k"->2 and "m"->3.

Comment: I see: perhaps spaces could make that point much clearer: "g o o g l e" yields "0 1 2 3 4 5".

Comment: ...? no, "g o o g l e" can't yield "0 1 2 3 4 5" because the number that a letter receives is always the same, it can't assign "0" to a "g" and then "3" to a "g". all the answers to this question have provided different ways of implementing this mapping of letters to integers 0<=n<=9, so I'd say it's pretty clear what the problem is, it could hardly be any clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If the macro is (as here) not written using expansion, you can work like xstring or pgf and leave the result in a macro which does expand:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter

\newcount\mycount
\newcommand*{\findtoken}[1]{%
  % input (#1): a b c d <anything else>
  %     output: 0 1 2 3 error
  \begingroup     % protect scratch macros
  \edef\@tempa{\expanded{#1}}%
  \@tempswafalse  % did anything match?
  \@tempcnta=\z@  % index of the list
  % loop
  \xdef\findtokenresult{}%
  \@for\@tempb:={a,b,c,d}\do{%
    % if they match, record the current index
    \ifx\@tempb\@tempa
      \@tempswatrue
%      \expandafter\aftergroup\the\@tempcnta
         \xdef\findtokenresult{\the\@tempcnta}%
    \fi
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  }% end of loop
  \if@tempswa\else
    \STOPCOMPILATION
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\lettera{a}
Checking whether \string\findtoken\ works:
\findtoken{\lettera}\findtokenresult,
\findtoken{a}\findtokenresult,
\findtoken{b}\findtokenresult,
\findtoken{c}\findtokenresult,
\findtoken{d}\findtokenresult.
% uncomment the next line to stop compilation:
% \findtoken{x}

% now, trying to assign \findtoken's expansion into \mycount:
\findtoken{c}\mycount\findtokenresult\relax
% ^ what to write above?! ^

\string\mycount's value is: \the\mycount.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an expandable implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\findtoken}{m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {a}{0}
    {b}{1}
    {c}{2}
    {d}{3}
   }
   {\errorstopmode\ERROR}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcount\mycount

\begin{document}

\def\lettera{a}
Checking whether \string\findtoken\ works:
\findtoken{\lettera},
\findtoken{a},
\findtoken{b},
\findtoken{c},
\findtoken{d}.
% uncomment the next line to stop compilation:
% \findtoken{x}

% now, trying to assign \findtoken's expansion into \mycount:
\mycount\findtoken{c}\relax

\string\mycount's value is: \the\mycount.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Is it possible? Yes.
- Is it possible if you insist on using the `\mycount\findtoken{a}` syntax? No. (unless you rewrite the `\findtoken` macro to be fully expandable)

  See the following code.

  ```
  %! TEX program = pdflatex
  \documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \makeatletter

  \newcount\mycount
  \newcommand*{\findtokenx}[2]{%
    % input (#1): a b c d <anything else>
    % input (#2): a single token to be placed immediately before the value
    %     output: 0 1 2 3 error
    \begingroup     % protect scratch macros
    \aftergroup#2%
    \edef\@tempa{\expanded{#1}}%
    \@tempswafalse  % did anything match?
    \@tempcnta=\z@  % index of the list
    % loop
    \@for\@tempb:={a,b,c,d}\do{%
      % if they match, record the current index
      \ifx\@tempb\@tempa
        \@tempswatrue
        \expandafter\aftergroup\the\@tempcnta
      \fi
      \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    }% end of loop
    \if@tempswa\else
      \STOPCOMPILATION
    \fi
    \endgroup
  }

  \newcommand*{\findtoken}[1]{%
      \findtokenx{#1}\empty
  }

  \makeatother
  \begin{document}
  \def\lettera{a}
  Checking whether \string\findtoken\ works:
  \findtoken{\lettera},
  \findtoken{a},
  \findtoken{b},
  \findtoken{c},
  \findtoken{d}.
  % uncomment the next line to stop compilation:
  % \findtoken{x}

  % now, trying to assign \findtoken's expansion into \mycount:
  \findtokenx{c}\mycount
  % ^ what to write above?! ^

  \string\mycount's value is: \the\mycount.
  \end{document}
  ```

  How it works should be relatively obvious, just trace through the logic.
- What's wrong with the original attempt? That `\begingroup` is not expandable.

  Read more:  [What is "expansion"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158827/250119), [Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645995/250119).

---

By the way, `\expandafter\aftergroup\the\counta` will only work as you expect if `\the\counta` expands to a single token (i.e. a one-digit number)

There are more quirks with the code (e.g. `\expanded` is probably not what you want to write there), but either way I avoid modifying unrelated parts so it's easy to compare with the original attempt.

Comment: Plus, reusing LaTeX's internal scratch variables for your own purpose is not a good idea, it might interfere with arbitrary other code. Without memory limitation it's better to make your own.